# Email Tag in HTML?

Tags: html

I have an IT class project that wants us to include a number of things in a website, most of which I'm familiar with. However, it mandates the "Use of at least one email tag." I can't find anything about this tag. Does it actually exist? My guess is they mean a mailto link or an email form or something. Am I missing anything here?

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, but I did know how a mailto link works. I was just curious if anyone knew anything about an extinct  tag or something that I was missing.

Comment: it probably means "mailto" tag.

Comment: Or `<input type=email>`

Comment: @null, that's literally all there is. There's a long list of things we're supposed to have. Number 15 is "Use of at least one email tag."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will take the user to their default mail software and start composing a new message to `example@somewhere.com`.

```
<a href="mailto:example@somewhere.com">Send email to example@somewhere.com</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use a `mailto:` is the only HTML email tag as far as I am aware of. You can specify your email, a subject, cc, bcc, and even some of the body :

`<a href="mailto:michael@domain.com?cc=email2@yourdomain.com&amp;subject=Email-subject&amp;body=Hi%20Michael%2C%0A%0A%3CFill%20out%20the%20body%3E">Send email</a>`

The`%20` is to spearate out spaces between words. More details [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The email tag would be `mailto:`. An example of this would be

```
<a href="mailto:joebloggs@gmail.com">Email me</a>
```

Which would display out as [Email me](http://example.com) in HTML and clicking on that link (not the one in this line because it's only an example) should open it in the email client you have set for emails.